# Send data from Azure vm (linux) to Azure blob storage container

Tags: linux, azure, azure-blob-storage, redhat

So here is the scenario.

I have 1 **vm linux machine** which is inside in a **vNet**. I want to copy file into azure blob storage **container**.

I have already put that file into /tmp folder. I have already installed the azure cli and azcopy.

I need your help.

What should I need to do now? I think I need access first either **system-assigned** or **user-assigned**.

What is the best practice in that regard? System-assigned or user-assigned.

Keep in mind that I have to create a **cron job** that will copy that file on daily basis from the vm and put into azure blob **storage**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is which type of Managed Identity you should use the answer is the same it always is in our industry: it depends.

Have a look at [What are managed identities for Azure resources? - Managed identity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types) for a detailed description about the two types of Managed Identities.

> **System-assigned**. Some Azure resources, such as virtual machines allow you to enable a managed identity directly on the resource.
>
> **User-assigned**. You may also create a managed identity as a standalone Azure resource. You can create a user-assigned managed identity and assign it to one or more Azure Resources.

Based on the information you provided at this time, I would expect a System-Assigned managed identity to be the best fit for now.